# wrap href link and id to last 3 characters in span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to wrap a `href` with and `id` to the last three characters wrapped in a `span`.

HTML

```
<span id="cartCost">€0.00 EUR</span>
```

The last three characters of the span will always be a currency code. The currency code will change automatically depending on your region. I am trying to wrap the last three characters (currency code) in a `href`. The href will be used to stimulate a select box and does not need a link just an ID (so even wrapping it the code in a div is sufficient).

I know I need to be working with `.each()`, `.wrapInner` and maybe `substring`. Anyway here is what I've been trying:

```
$('#cartCost').each(function() {
   var count = $(this).text( text.substring(-3)
    code  = $(count).text();
    $(code).wrapInner('<a href="#" id="open">');
})​
```

The end result should look like this:

```
<span id="cartCost">€0.00 <a href="#" id="open">EUR</a></span>
```

Any solutions, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st id must be unique .. use classes instead

2nd:

```
$('.cartCost').each(function() {
   // get the text and use trim to avoid left and right white spaces
   var count = $.trim($(this).text());
   // get last three .. substring() needs start index and end index 
    var lastthree = count.substring(count.length - 3 , count.length);
   // replace last three with html code we want
    var replaceit = count.replace(lastthree , '<a href="#" class="open">'+ lastthree +'</a>');
   // append the new value as a html using .html() 
    $(this).html(replaceit);
})
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/r2087yn3/2/)

Comment: Thank you. Is it good practice to use class over id in cases like this? or is it irrelevant?

Comment: @Panoply always use id just for one element .. if you use more elements with same id it will just will select the first one of them  .. so id should be unique for element .. Good Luck :-)

Comment: @Panoply additional .. you can use id and class for same element like <div id="anyId" class="anyClass"></div> .. sorry but I find I should let you know that as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hey after playing a little with a fiddle, this is the result I could come up with

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var content = $('#cartCost').html();
        var code  = content.substr(-3);

        var newCode = "<a href='#' id='open'>" + code + "</a>";
        var newContent = content.replace(code, newCode); 
       $('#cartCost').html(newContent);
    });

</script>

<span id="cartCost">€0.00 EUR</span>
```

Here is the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xLn0hna2/)

Comment: The `substr` method is a great idea, but it does not work for IE 8 or below

Comment: Is anyone still using ie8 then? That's so 2007